# Does higher Hertz mean a higher electric bill?

Tags: electricity, everyday-life, frequency, power, electronics

Suppose my electric utility is meant to provide power at 60 hertz, but instead it provides it at 61 hertz. Would my electric bill be higher? Assume I run the same appliances for the same amount of time in each scenario.

Comment: It depends what impedance your load presents at 60 Hz vs 61 Hz. Its theoretically possible for one device to be a tiny tiny bit cheaper and another to be a tiny bit more expensive. In reality unless you're using very high power devices, doubt you will notice.

Comment: The power company charges you for Real Power, which is manifest in their meter regardless of the Hz or anything else

Comment: In practice, that shouldn't happen. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_clock#Synchronous_electric_clock "Although utility load variations cause frequency fluctuations which may result in errors of a few seconds during the course of a day, utilities periodically adjust the frequency of their current using UTC atomic clock time so that the total number of cycles in a day gives an average frequency that is exactly the nominal value, so synchronous clocks do not accumulate error". Such a clock designed for 60 Hz running on 61 Hz would run fast by ~23m 36.4s per day.

Comment: But a lower frequency Hertz less?

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends on what device consumes electricity. If it is simple resistor then
$$I(t)\sim U(t)=U_{max}cos(\omega t)$$
and there is no phase shift, so for time T the device will consume energy, equal to
$$\int Ndt \sim \int U^2dt\sim U_{max}T$$
independently from frequency $\omega$. Even if the current is phase shifted but phase difference is constant and $I_{max}\sim U_{max}$ then power still will not depend on frequency.
But for even simple chains like RLC circuit there will be high dependence on input frequency, so there is no general answer for you question. I can only be sure that most of your devices has stabilizers of voltage and frequency, so gain of power will not highly change because of 1 extra hertz.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the question is more relevant to EE.se.

Anyway:

1. The frequency is one of the most strictly controlled parameters of the utility power. The voltage may vary, depending on where you are, e.g. +/- 10%, but the only way to get 61Hz power is to disconnect from the utility grid and use not very good generator. From the wall socket, you will hardly get something more than, e.g. 60.000001 hertz.

Maintaining an exact frequency is very, very important for the grid itself and much less for the consumers.

2. If you somehow managed to get 61 hertz power: SOME appliances will consume some more electricity. Some of them will do more work in return - e.g. a fridge compressor will rotate proportionally faster, but it will also cool the fridge content faster so the thermostat will allow it to run for shorter periods. A water pump will pump some more water, etc...

A very cheap LED lightbulb (that uses capacitive divider internally) will also consume a bit more electricity and will shine proportionally brighter. On the other hand, the normal voltage variation will generally have much stronger effect on the same lightbulb.

3. Measurement: the old rotary electric meters used to depend on the frequency for the exact measurement of the consumed electricity. They may measure somewhat more or less at higher frequency. Probably more, at the first glance. The modern electronic meters behave better in this regard.